# How to format/access inner boxplots of a violin catplot in seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot, catplot

[image: seaborn catplot with kind=violin]

I'm looking to change the formatting of the inner boxplots for the violin plots within this catplot. I have tried using the violinplot parameter `inner_kws=dict(box_width=15, whis_width=2, color=".8")` to no avail.

code used

```
p = sns.catplot(data=sample4, x='modelID', y='error', hue='isDF', size=3, kind='violin', split=True, height=5, aspect=1.8, inner='box', fill=False, inner_kws=dict(box_width=15, whis_width=2, color=".8"))
p.set(ylabel='occupancy error', title='Error distribution by model type for busy variable legs')
p.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)

for i,ax in enumerate(p.axes.flatten()):
    ax.axhline(0.2, ls='--', color='k', alpha=0.1, zorder=0)
    ax.axhline(-0.2, ls='--', color='k', alpha=0.1, zorder=0)
    ax.axhline(0, ls='--', color='k', alpha=0.3, zorder=0)
```

sample data

```
           modelID isDF     error
622   MonthAverage   No -0.182288
1096       S-AVG-1   No  0.122069
1277       S-AVG-4   No  0.105147
2189      NoChange  Yes -0.189221
1250       S-AVG-4   No -0.037150
1530           GMM  Yes  0.068475
1553           GMM  Yes -0.543998
789   MonthAverage   No -0.164985
1061       S-AVG-1   No  0.064435
1602  MonthAverage  Yes -0.062130
448            GMM   No  0.478873
1513           GMM  Yes  0.166998
1349       S-AVG-4   No -0.069806
1860           GAM  Yes  0.034769
830       NoChange   No -0.150372
1151       S-AVG-1   No -0.142022
846       NoChange   No -0.385930
1847           GAM  Yes  0.102694
1049       S-AVG-1   No  0.095174
921       NoChange   No -0.102451
```

Comment: Running your code does not work for me. catplot() does not have a keyword argument size.

Comment: @ciaran  Are you running the latest seaborn version? `inner_kws` seems to be new in version 0.13.  Note that the "box" is drawn as two lines, one thick for the "box" and one thin for the "whis". In the latest version, each half of the violin gets its own boxplot (in older versions, they got a shared boxplot).

Comment: After removing size, the formatting with inner_kws also works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @JohanC - turn that into an answer for kudos. Thanks for the help folks. Apologies for legacy keywords from previous plots. Interesting that they didn't cause problems for me.